# Assigning a list within a loop

Tags: c

I have the following function to get the distance between some points:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int add_coords(size_t size, float coords[size][2])
{
    float distance = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < size-1; i++) {
        float this[2] = coords[i]; // not allowed
        float next[2] = coords[i+1];
        distance = sqrt(pow(this[0] - next[0]),2) + pow(this[1] - next[1]),2));
    }
    return distance;
}
int main(void)
{
    float coords[][2] = {{1,3}, {5,7}, {-2,-3}};
    float distance = add_coords(sizeof coords / sizeof *coords, coords);
    
    printf("The distance is %.2f\n", distance);
}
```

What would be the best way to do the following?

```
float this[2] = coords[i];
```

Current what I'm doing is the following, this it was a bit tricky to come up with:

```
// pointer to array of two
float (*this)[2], (*next)[2];

for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
    this = &coords[i];
    next = &coords[i+1];
    distance += sqrtf(powf((*this)[0] - (*next)[0],2) + powf((*this)[1] - *(next)[1],2));
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `distance +=` instead of `distance =` and rename `add_coords` to `cumulative_distance_between_coords`, also you may use `t_point` instead of `t_coords`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use a struct, this would avoid any unwanted undefined behavior:

```c
typedef struct coords {
float x;
float y;
} t_coords


// ...

t_coords coords = {.x= coords[i][0], .y=coords[i][1]};
```

Also you should be careful to declare your array coords with float `f`:

```c
{{1f,3f}, {5f,7f}, {-2f,-3f}};
```